# Регулярное выражение для пароля в атрибутах

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, mvc, валидация, razor

Приложение Asp.NET MVC, движок Razor, со стандартным jquery.validate
Есть модель:

```
public class ChangePassViewModel
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Web_User_OldPassRequiredError")]
    [MinLength(9, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Web_User_PassLengthError")]
    public string OldPass { get; set; }

    [Required (ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Web_User_NewPassRequiredError")]
    [MinLength(9, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Web_User_PassLengthError")]
    public string NewPass { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Web_User_NewPassRepeaterRequiredError")]
    [MinLength(9, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Web_User_PassLengthError")]
    [Compare("NewPass", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Web_User_OldNewPassCompareError")]
    public string NewPassRepeat { get; set; }
}
```

Для всех полей хочу добавить проверку регулярным выражением на условия:

1. Содержать обязательно символы латинского алфавита в верхнем и нижнем регистре.
2. Содержать обязательно цифры.
3. Недопустимо вводить спецсимволы (*,.<>/?!@&^%$#(){}[]).

Добавляю

```
[RegularExpression(@"[A - Za - z0 - 9]", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Web_User_PassFormatError")]
```

во View

```
<div class="col-md-6">@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.OldPass, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = 20 })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.OldPass)
```

При работе получается, что на введённые поля
"Abc12345678"
"ABCs1092873918"
Выходит ошибка

**Вопрос**
Как построить правильно регулярное выражение для атрибута [RegularExpression]?

Comment: во-первых уберите пробелы. во-вторых? это будет проверка на допустимые символы, а еще надо проверить, что каждый из классов присутствует

Comment: Недопустимо наличие спецсимволов в пароле? о_О Вы специально хотите пароль послабее, да?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте вот такое регулярное выражение: `@"^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{9,}$"`. Оно также проверяет минимальную длину 9, соответствующий атрибут можно убрать.

Comment: Немного поправил.

Comment: Сработало. Спасибо.